# Customizing Google Chart's svg using JS not works on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, svg

I'm using Google Charts to create charts on my app.

Due to some limitations of the api, after the generation of the svg I change some elements using direct JS manipulation. I do things like add text and move elements.

This works perfectly on Android, but on iOS my changes are ignored.

Here is the expected result using Android. I moved the label and update it after the svg generation.

[image: SVG manipulation on Android (chart zoomed)]

And here the result on iOS. Label not moved and not updated.

[image: SVG manipulation on iOS (chart zoomed)]

How to fix this issue? I read something about add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"`, but the generation of the svg is responsability of Google API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that everytime I was comparing a text or change a text I was using `innerHTML` and not `textContent`. The right was is always use `textContent` when dealing with the `<text>` element of SVG.